# Jsf 2 - DataTable não seleciona a linha no clique e não reconhece paginação

Tags: java, jsf

Estou utilizando o `Jsf` 2 SEM `Primefaces` e gostaria de saber como eu faço pra resolver o seguinte problema:

Minha `DataTable` está carregando os dados corretamente, mas ela não me permite selecionar a linha que foi carregada dentro dela de jeito nenhum, consta como se ela me bloqueia essa ação. E ela também não reconhece a paginação que eu adicionei(quando minha página carrega, não está exibindo os botões de Anterior, Próximo, etc...) Segue meu `Xhtml` completo abaixo:

```
<ui:composition template="/templates/default.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="VPRS-ControleFaixas - Consulta" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
    <table id="tabela_interna" width="100%" cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" height="100%" colspan="3">
            <h:graphicImage library="imagens" width="70%" name="tit_controle_faixa.gif"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td width ="100%" height="100%">
        <h:outputText value="Produto" />
        <h:selectOneMenu style="width : 388px; height : 16px;">
        <f:selectItems value="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.listaProduto}" var="produto"
        itemValue="#{produto.codProduto}" itemLabel="#{produto.nomeProduto}"></f:selectItems>
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td width ="100%" height="100%" colspan="3">

        <h:dataTable value="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.listaFaixa}" var="faixaProduto" 
        paginator="true" rows="15" paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} >{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        selectionMode="single" selection="# {consultarFaixaProdutoBean.faixaProdutoVO}" rowKey="#{faixaProduto.codProduto}">
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Produto</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.codProduto}-#{faixaProduto.nomeProduto}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Qtd. Propostas</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.qtdFaixaPpsta}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Validade (dias)</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.numDiasValPpsta}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Desativação (dias)</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.numDiasDesatPpsta}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Ultima Atual.</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.dtUltAtualizacao}
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Responsável</f:facet>
        #{faixaProduto.cdRespUltimaAtualizacao}
        </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <table id="tabela_botoes" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >border="0" width="30%">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td>
                        <h:commandButton value="Consultar" action="# {consultarFaixaProdutoBean.consultar}" styleClass="margem_botoes button" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <h:commandButton value="Nova Consulta" action="# {consultarFaixaProdutoBean.novaConsulta}" styleClass="margem_botoes button" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ui:define>
        </ui:composition>
        </html>
```

Para o projeto que estou fazendo, eu não posso utilizar `PrimeFaces` e nem `Richfaces` de maneira nenhuma. Quem souber me responder como eu faço essas ações sem eles eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue a minha solução em duas partes:

**1ª - A Linha não estava selecionando pelo clique do mouse:**

Bom, acabei descobrindo uma forma que seleciona através de JavaScript, no link a seguir mostra como fazer essa tarefá e já com o exemplo: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

**2ª - Como fazer uma paginação:**

Graças ao link abaixo, consegui encontrar a solução do meu problema: http://www.roytuts.com/effective-pagination-example-in-jsf-2/

Querem conferir como ela ficou? Então mostrarei logo abaixo hehe:

1º Cria uma classe chamada Paginacao, para controlar todos os eventos da tarefa, observem a classe Paginacao.java:

```
package br.com.bradseg.vprs.controlefaixas.crud.model.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.component.UICommand;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

public class Paginacao {

    private int totalLinha;
    private int primeiraLinha;
    private int totalPaginas;
    private Integer[] paginas;
    private int paginaAtual;
    private List listaTotal;
    private List listaAux;

    public static final int LINHAS_POR_PAGINA = 15;
    public static final int INTERVALO_PAGINAS = 10; 

    public Paginacao(List listaTotal) {
        this.listaTotal = listaTotal;
        carregaPaginacao();
    }

    // Ações da Paginação -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public void carregaPaginacao() {

        totalLinha = listaTotal.size();

        // Set paginaAtual, totalPaginas e paginas.
        paginaAtual = (totalLinha / LINHAS_POR_PAGINA) - ((totalLinha - primeiraLinha) / LINHAS_POR_PAGINA) + 1;
        totalPaginas = (totalLinha / LINHAS_POR_PAGINA) + ((totalLinha % LINHAS_POR_PAGINA != 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int tamanhoPaginas = Math.min(INTERVALO_PAGINAS, totalPaginas);
        paginas = new Integer[tamanhoPaginas];

        int primeiraPagina = Math.min(Math.max(0, paginaAtual - (INTERVALO_PAGINAS / 2)), totalPaginas - tamanhoPaginas);

        // Cria as paginas.
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanhoPaginas; i++) {
            paginas[i] = ++ primeiraPagina;
        }
        carregaDataTable();
    }

    public void carregaDataTable(){

        listaAux = new ArrayList<FaixaProdutoVO>();

        int organizador = (paginaAtual * LINHAS_POR_PAGINA) -  LINHAS_POR_PAGINA;
        int limite =  (paginaAtual * LINHAS_POR_PAGINA);
        for(int i = organizador; i<limite; i++){
            if(totalLinha > i){
                Object o = new Object();
                o = listaTotal.get(i); 
                listaAux.add(o);
            } else{
                break;
            }

        }

    }

    public void primeiraPagina() {
        pagina(0);
    }

    public void proximaPagina() {
        pagina(primeiraLinha + LINHAS_POR_PAGINA);

    }

    public void paginaAnterior() {
        pagina(primeiraLinha - LINHAS_POR_PAGINA);
    }

    public void ultimaPagina() {
        pagina(totalLinha - ((totalLinha % LINHAS_POR_PAGINA != 0) ? totalLinha % LINHAS_POR_PAGINA : LINHAS_POR_PAGINA));

    }

    public void pagina(ActionEvent event) {        
        pagina(((Integer) ((UICommand) event.getComponent()).getValue() - 1) * LINHAS_POR_PAGINA);
    }

    private void pagina(int primeiraLinha) {
        this.primeiraLinha = primeiraLinha;
        carregaPaginacao();
    }

    /**
     * @return the totalLinha
     */
     public int getTotalLinha() {
        return totalLinha;
    }

    /**
     * @param totalLinha the totalLinha to set
     */
     public void setTotalLinha(int totalLinha) {
         this.totalLinha = totalLinha;
     }

     /**
      * @return the primeiraLinha
      */
     public int getPrimeiraLinha() {
         return primeiraLinha;
     }

     /**
      * @param primeiraLinha the primeiraLinha to set
      */
     public void setPrimeiraLinha(int primeiraLinha) {
         this.primeiraLinha = primeiraLinha;
     }

     /**
      * @return the totalPaginas
      */
     public int getTotalPaginas() {
         return totalPaginas;
     }

     /**
      * @param totalPaginas the totalPaginas to set
      */
     public void setTotalPaginas(int totalPaginas) {
         this.totalPaginas = totalPaginas;
     }

     /**
      * @return the paginas
      */
     public Integer[] getPaginas() {
         return paginas;
     }

     /**
      * @param paginas the paginas to set
      */
     public void setPaginas(Integer[] paginas) {
         this.paginas = paginas;
     }

     /**
      * @return the paginaAtual
      */
     public int getPaginaAtual() {
         return paginaAtual;
     }

     /**
      * @param paginaAtual the paginaAtual to set
      */
     public void setPaginaAtual(int paginaAtual) {
         this.paginaAtual = paginaAtual;
     }

     /**
      * @return the listaAux
      */
     public List getListaAux() {
         return listaAux;
     }

     /**
      * @param listaAux the listaAux to set
      */
     public void setListaAux(List listaAux) {
         this.listaAux = listaAux;
     }



}
```

2º no meu ManagedBean, criei um objeto da classe Paginacao, conforme abaixo (ConsultarFaixaProdutoBean.java):

```
@Controller
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped 
public class ConsultarFaixaProdutoBean extends BaseController implements Serializable {

private Paginacao paginacao;

    private FaixaProdutoVO faixaProdutoVO;

    private List<FaixaProdutoVO> listaTotal;
    private List<FaixaProdutoVO> listaFaixa;

@PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        faixaProdutoVO = new FaixaProdutoVO();
        listaTotal = faixaProdutoFacade.obterListaFaixaProduto(faixaProdutoVO);

        if (listaTotal != null && !listaTotal.isEmpty()){
            aplicarPaginacao();
        }
    }

    public void aplicarPaginacao(){
        if(listaFaixa == null){
            paginacao = new Paginacao(listaTotal);
        }else{
            paginacao.carregaPaginacao();
        }

        setListaFaixa((List<FaixaProdutoVO>)paginacao.getListaAux());
    }

//Setters e Getters
}
```

3º - Enfim, segue a minha página Xhtml, como ele chama as suas propriedades:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:form id="content">
    <ui:composition template="/templates/default.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">

    <h:outputScript library="js" name="util.js" />

        <table id="tabela_interna" width="100%" cellpadding="0"
            cellspacing="1">
    <tr>
            <td width ="100%" height="100%" colspan="3"> 
            <h:form>

            <h:dataTable  id="tableFaixa" value="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.listaFaixa}" var="faixaProduto" 
            selectionMode="single" selection="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.faixaProdutoVO}" rowKey="#{faixaProduto.codProduto}" width ="100%" height="100%">
        <h:column>
         <input type="radio" class="optionbutton" name="rdbOption" onclick="javascript:salvaProdutoCookie();"
                value="#{faixaProduto.codProduto}" />  
        </h:column>

            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Produto</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.codProduto}-#{faixaProduto.nomeProduto}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Qtd. Propostas</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.qtdFaixaPpsta}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Validade (dias)</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.numDiasValPpsta}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Desativação (dias)</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.numDiasDesatPpsta}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Ultima Atual.</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.dtUltAtualizacao}
            </h:column>
            <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">Responsável</f:facet>
            #{faixaProduto.cdRespUltimaAtualizacao}
            </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>  
            </h:form>
            <br />
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
 <table>
             <tr>
             <td>
             <h:form>
            <!--Botoes de Paginacao-->
            <h:commandLink value="Primeiro" action="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.primeiraPagina}"
                             disabled="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.primeiraLinha == 0}" />  <span></span>
            <h:commandLink value="Anterior" action="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.paginaAnterior}"
                             disabled="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.primeiraLinha == 0}" /> <span></span>
                  <ui:repeat value="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.paginas}" var="pagina">
                <h:commandLink value="#{pagina}" actionListener="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.pagina}"
                               rendered="#{pagina != consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.paginaAtual}" />
                <h:outputText value="&lt;b&gt;#{pagina}&lt;/b&gt;" escape="false"
                              rendered="#{pagina == consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.paginaAtual}" />
            </ui:repeat> <span></span>
            <h:commandLink value="Próximo" action="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.proximaPagina}"
                             disabled="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.primeiraLinha + 15 >= consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.totalLinha}" /> <span></span>
            <h:commandLink value="Último" action="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.ultimaPagina}" 
                             disabled="#{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.primeiraLinha + 15 >= consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.totalLinha}" /> <span></span>
            <h:outputText value="Pagina #{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.paginaAtual} / #{consultarFaixaProdutoBean.paginacao.totalPaginas}" /> 
            <br />


            </h:form>
            </td>
            </tr>
             </table>

            </ui:define>

    </ui:composition>
    </h:form>
    </html>
```